# Text classification with R and SVM. Matrix features

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, text-classification

I am playing a bit with text classification and SVM.

My understanding is that typically the way to pick up the features for the training matrix is essentially to use a "bag of words" where we essentially end up with a matrix with as many columns as different words are in our document and the values of such columns is the number of occurrences per word per document (of course each document is represented by a single row).

So that all works fine, I can train my algorithm and so on, but sometimes i get an error like

> Error during wrapup: test data does not match model !

By digging it a bit, I found the answer in this question [Error in predict.svm: test data does not match model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265305/error-in-predict-svm-test-data-does-not-match-model) which essentially says that **if your model has features A, B and C, then your new data to be classified should contain columns A, B and C**. Of course **with text this is a bit tricky, my new documents to classify might contain words that have never been seen by the classifier with the training set.**

More specifically I am using the RTextTools library whith uses SparseM and tm libraries internally, the object used to train the svm is of type "matrix.csr".

Regardless of the specifics of the library my question is, is there any technique in document classification to ensure that the fact that training documents and new documents have different words will not prevent new data from being classified?

**UPDATE** The solution suggested by @lejlot is very simple to achieve in RTextTools by simply making use of the **originalMatrix** optional parameter when using the **create_matrix** function. Essentially, originalMatrix should be the SAME matrix that one creates when one uses the create_matrix function for TRAINING the data. So after you have trained your data and have your models, keep also the original document matrix, when using new examples, make sure of using such object when creating the new matrix for your prediction set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regardless of the specifics of the library my question is, is there any technique in document classification to ensure that the fact that training documents and new documents have different words will not prevent new data from being classified?

Yes, and it is very trivial one. Before applying any training or classification you create a preprocessing object, which is supposed to map text to your vector representation. In particular - it **stores whole vocabulary used for training**. Later on you reuse the same preprocessing object on test documents, and you simply ignore words from outside of vocabulary stored before (OOV words, as they are often refered in the literature).

Obviously there are plenty other more "heuristic" approaches, where instead of discarding you try to map them to existing words (although it is less theoreticalyy justified). Rather - you should create intermediate representation, which will be your new "preprocessing" object which can handle OOV words (through some levenstein distance mapping etc.).